# Angular Tutorial Clarification doesn't show properly.

Tags: angular

Hey I was doing this tutorial in Angular: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/geofire-location-queries-with-google-maps/
including following all the instructions in the video tutorial. But when I run the the finished project I get the basic Welcome to Angular page.

Has someone else here also did this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First inn the app.modules.ts in declaration add GoogleMapComponent if it is not there, like so:

```
// do not forget to import GoogleMapComponent from a file
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        GoogleMapComponent,
        ...
      ]
```

Then in the app.component.html add to file or replace all with next tag:

```
<google-map></google-map>
```

Comment: Your answer solves my first part. Thanks! I continued to write the code and after typing for applying the Firebase and all. I get a blank page.  And no errors appear on the CLI.

Comment: Check the console in the browser. P.s. If the answer was helpful consider rating and mark as completed the answer, thank you.